# Angular trigger form submit with submit status/class programmatically

Tags: angular

I have a series of questions in a form that get displayed one at a time. The user can complete them and go backwards & forwards.

I am wiring in the left & right arrow keys to allow the user to do this more easily using `onkeypress`. The event for the right arrow triggers the code for submitting the form.

However, the form controls have validation based on the submitted state of the form, i.e. `[ngClass]="{ 'was-validated': form.submitted }"`.

When the user gets to the last question completed with the right arrow key, the error message displays, but the validation doesn't show because the `form.submitted` property is `false`. The property is read only so I can't manually set it, and I have tried the following:

```
this._form.form.markAllAsTouched();
this._form.form.markAsTouched();
this._form.ngSubmit.emit();
```

Any idea how I trigger this submit?

Here's a StackBlitz showing a form submit that turns the form green, and an event submit that doesn't:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfxcjv?file=src/main.ts

Comment: can you put a sample for the template and component?

Comment: @ZsoltBalint example added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `this.form.onSubmit(null);` or `this.form.onSubmit(undefined);` in your `click` function.